# Custom URI Scheme

Tags: android, uri

I'd like to be able to open my Android app from a URL. So in the AndroidManifest.xml I put this code:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/apikey" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.myApp.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="uritest" android:host="com.myApp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But when I go into my browser on the phone and type in "uritest://com.myApp" in the URL bar, it Google searches it instead of opening the app like I would expect it to. Is there something that I'm doing incorrectly? Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for Chrome on Android not firing intent when links are clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706667/workaround-for-chrome-on-android-not-firing-intent-when-links-are-clicked)

Comment: @matiash I tried that, it still didn't work.