# Rediection not working from file system in emulator

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, android-emulator

I am newbie to Phonegap so help me to getout from this issue.

In my application i have to redirect to List.html file while click on button1, I wrote code like this,

a href='#' onClick='test();' id="button"> button1

function test()

```
 {
       window.location="/home/swift-03/phonegapexamples/MySmartCity/www/List.html";

 }
```

But while running on emulator it showing file not found.whether i should use my local ip address to redirect to my List.html in local directory.

But when i am redirecting to www.google.com  it is working fine.

function test()

```
 {
       window.location="www.google.com";

 }
```

This is redirecting to google page.

Please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: did you try accessing from the root? in this case `window.location="../home/swift-03/phonegapexamples/MySmartCity/www/List.html"` @Ashok kumar

Comment: thanks for reply. yes i tried from root,but button is not responding.do i need to use ip address of mine?@Arty

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the original HTML that is showing  `button1` is in the same file directory, you would have to do:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <input type="button" href='#' onClick='test();' id="button" value="button1" ></input>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

`function test(){
       /* Provideed master.html is in the same directory as the html that has button1*/
       window.location=" ./master.html";
}`

I hope this makes sense. If you want to access two directories above then you would have to use `../master.html` but in this case, if the file is in the same directory you would have to do `./master.html`

Comment: @Atry ,thankyou for replay, Both calling and called files are in same directory. but still it is showing file not found

Comment: maybe try `document.location = "./List.html";` @Ashokkumar

Comment: ,Sorry this was not working.on Browser it was running, but in emulator it was not running

Comment: You could check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036793/android-browser-facebook-redirect-does-not-always-trigger-intent-for-url), it might help. @Ashokkumar

Comment: thank you, I solved it. I did't given any path to html file.just mentioned file name without any path.it worked for me. Thank you for  your support.@Arty